# Group number of days event has occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

My table called weather:

```
snowfall dayoftheyear observationdate
0.1       28           2019-01-28
1.9       67           2019-03-08
0.13      316          2019-11-12
```

I have a total of 137 rows with random day of the year max being 365 and max observation date being 2019-12-31.

My objective is to understand for each month between 2019 to 2020, how many days for each month did the snowfall occur. That means, if for Jan there were 12 occurrences of observation_date, then 12 is the answer. How to accomplish this? I tried-

```
select 
  sum(snowfall ) precipitation,   
  right(observation_date, 7) EachMonth
from weather
where observation_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' and city = 'Olympia' and snowfall  > 0
group by EachMonth
order by EachMonth
```

Doing this I receive totals for each date like-

```
snowfall EachMonth
0.24     9-01-04
```

But I don't get the sum total of how many days by each month it snowed.
Desired result

```
TotalDaysofSnowfall  EachMonth
4                     01
7                     08
```

Comment: And please provide your desired results.

Comment: @DaleK thanks edited with desired result. Eachmonth represents a month. example 08 is august

Comment: `COUNT(*)`? so long as you only ever have one observation per day.

Comment: @DaleK How do I use COUNT(*) in this situation. Count of observation_date by what? Please provide script

Comment: Literally add `count(*)` as a column in your query (and feel free to check the documentation if you are unclear). It counts rows, so if you have at most 1 row per day it should give what you want. Unfortunately your sample data doesn't match your desired results.

Comment: I apologize. i still dont understand. Thank you though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249684/discussion-between-jay-janardhan-and-dale-k).

Answer (score 0):

As Dale mention use `count(*)`. And you can't use column alias in the `GROUP BY`

```
select 
     count(*) as TotalDaysofSnowfall,  
     datepart(month, observation_date) as EachMonth
from  
     weather
where 
     observation_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' 
 and city      = 'Olympia' 
 and snowfall  > 0
group by 
     datepart(month, observation_date)
order by 
     EachMonth
```

Comment: Syntax error: unexpected 'datepart'

Comment: I replaced datepart with left(observation_date, 7) as EachMonth and it worked